# Deploying software made in Visual C# Express (2010)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, deployment

7 Questions:

1 Can I sell the software I make in it?
2 What kind of licenses am I allowed to use?
3 Any templates for Terms of Use & Conditions?
4 Can I just distribute the exe in the /Release folder?
5 What if I use class libraries?
6 How do I stop people from installing it after the trial period is up?
7 How do I make a custom installing package?

Comment: it would be nice if the questions were numbered for ease of reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, you have in [Microsoft Offical
  websige of Visual Studio 2010
  Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/), writed "You can use it
  for commercial proposes".
- Licensing is your call, because you
  write a software.
- TOS of a Express Edition you can find
  at Microsoft webpages.
- Yes you can redistribute executable
  files.